# Delete Files with Windows Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

There is a shared folder in my `D` drive as `works` (`D:\works`). I need to delete all the files in that folder and sub folders `except word and excel files` in there. how can i do this ?

Comment: try if `del /[!*.DOC !*.XLS] *` works.. Be in `D:/Works` folder first...

Comment: @FahimParkar Your code is not working. got this error. `Invalid switch - "!*.DOC".`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to exclude file patterns using del. See the answer I posted below, that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar to what this guy's done: http://www.codesingh.com/2009/08/using-robocopy-to-delete-old-files-from.html

Something like this should work:

```
mkdir D:\_tempDelete
robocopy D:\works D:\_tempDelete /e /MOVE /XF *.xls* *.doc*
rmdir D:\_tempDelete /s /q
```

Provided you have permissions to create and delete folders on D:. Otherwise you could just move the files somewhere on your local drive and delete them from there.

Comment: what is `robocopy` ? not working in my computer. `'robocopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: It's standard in Vista and Win 7. Are you running XP? I think you can get it for XP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy