# Delete a folder which name starts with something in command prompt (batch)

Tags: batch-file, command, command-prompt

I read and tried some code from

1. [What's the fastest way to delete a large folder in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186737/whats-the-fastest-way-to-delete-a-large-folder-in-windows) (`rmdir /s /q folder`)
2. [Delete Files with Windows Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170560/delete-files-with-windows-command-prompt)

I want to create a batch which delete a folder which name starts with `Test_`. I have a folder `D:\Test_123_19_10_2012`.

How to write in batch or command prompt ? Need regular expression ?

Thank you for patience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go

```
for /d %%a in (D:\Test_*) do rd %%a /q
```

The `for` loop is necessary as it seems `rd` doesn't support wildcards.